# Getting output from the second node instead from the first

Tags: java, linked-list

What am I trying to do is take user inputs as nodes and adding them to the front of the Linked List. Then print all elements but I am getting the output from the second node instead from the first. I am not sure what is wrong with the input or the printList method.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    Node head;
    static class Node{
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node(int d) {
            this.data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }
    public void push(int newData){
        Node newNode = new Node(newData);
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
    public void printList(){
        Node temp = head;
        while(temp != null){
            System.out.println(temp.data);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution llist = new Solution();
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            int input = sc.nextInt();
            if(sc.hasNextLine()) llist.push(input);
        }
        llist.printList();
    }
}
```

INPUT:

```
5
383
484
392
975
321
```

Expected Output:

```
321
975
392
484
383
```

Output:

```
975
392
484
383
```

Comment: Don't get too riled up @tygvertw4cftw4crw ! Scott Hunter is providing very good advice. Part of becoming a good programmer is developing experience in debugging one's own programs. We have all been there at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the condition in your `main` method:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution llist = new Solution();
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            int input = sc.nextInt();
            if(sc.hasNextLine()) llist.push(input); // BIG PROBLEM HERE
        }
        llist.printList();
    }
```

What this does is it executes `llist.push(imput);` only if there are still lines in the scanner. This means that the last number you read from the scanner will not be added to your `llist`.

To solve your problem, I think removing your `if` condition should do the trick.

Comment: I have done it because of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68061019/16276488

Comment: I don't think you need to call `sc.nextLine()` between each input. But assuming that you need to call `sc.nextLine()`, what you meant to write was `if(sc.hasNextLine()) sc.nextLine();`.

Comment: Do I need to write nextLine everytime or is there any other way?